# How mark incoming variable as __block?

Tags: objective-c

all. 
I have a method:

```
-(void)connectToServer:(NSError**)error{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         //bla bla bla code;
         *error=[NSError bla bla bla];
    }
}
```

But after that error variable no modificated. Its no block variable. How can i modify this method for mark (NSError**)error as __block variable. If __block varibale used only for local variables?

Now i solve the problem with organization local variable with __block attribute:

```
-(void)connectToServer:(NSError**)error{
    __block NSError *localError=*error;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         //bla bla bla code;
         localError=[NSError bla bla bla];
    }
    *error=localError;
}
```

But this solution not like my, because i need redeclare __block NSError *localError=*error;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mu.

What you're doing doesn't make much sense. The `connectToServer:` method is quite likely going to return before that block sets the `error` variable, which means the caller isn't going to have a valid object to look at.

You need to have the block call another method to handle any errors that result, or run the block synchronously so that `connectToServer:` doesn't return before the block has finished.

Also, in the second case you should be following [Cocoa convention for error handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC) and indicating that an error occurred via the direct return of the method.

This should be rewritten as either:

```
- (void)connectToServer
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //bla bla bla code including error generation
        dispatch_sync(/* Get appropriate queue; probably main */, ^{
            // Handle error somehow
        });
    });
}
```

Or:

```
- (BOOL)connectToServer: (NSError **)e
{
    __block BOOL success = NO;
    // Note: dispatch_sync()
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //bla bla bla code;
        success = /* Get success value */;
        *e = /* Get error */;
    });
    return success;
}
```

Comment: no no, in seccond my code work fine. It's ok. I validate error variable few times, and go out function. My issue is that: how can i declare __block NSError * e = nil; Without in local variable?and generally you can do

Comment: Good answer, though returning an `NSError` is very uncommon in Cocoa (I don't know of a single framework method that does this). If you don't use the return value otherwise, you'd usually return a `BOOL` to indicate success/failure and return the actual error indirectly. I'm not saying that it's "wrong" in any way, it's just that I wouldn't expect this behavior, being used to Cocoa's conventions.

Comment: @omz: You're right to point that out; there's so many things weird about this code that I just stopped, but I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Bimawa: I really don't understand what you're saying. You can't reliably get a return value from a block that's running asynchronously on a dispatch queue. You need to _wait_ for the return value, whether that's by running the block synchronously or by doing a callback from within the enqueued block.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, i waiting result in another tread 3 secs, if connect not respond, i get error pointer and write here new error about Lost connections. I not have a trouble there. I'm interested in, whether it is possible to declare a variable __block in the incoming parameters of the method? And not to create a local variable, as in the second case?

Comment: @Bimawa: You don't need that `NSError` double pointer to be put into a `__block` variable; you can dereference it and set that, as my second code snippet demonstrates and as s.bandara has already told you.

Comment: It seems I began to understand. Thx a lot guys.

Answer (score 3):

To modify `error` from within the block you don't need a local `__block` scope variable. Assigning `*error = [NSError bla];` directly will already do.

This works because `error` is captured by the block in local scope. While `error` cannot be modified, it *can* be dereferenced to the address where some `NSError *x` is stored, and this `x` can indeed be changed from within the block.

However, you will need to be absolutely certain that whatever variable `NSError *x` is being referenced by `error` is sufficiently persistent.

Comment: guys, i can't modify non block variable in block function. I need mark this variable like __block (from appleDocs" "Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the __block storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable.")

Comment: I see where you are coming from but this does not apply here. `error` never changes. We are dereferencing `error` and modify its target.